# Java Set - how to sort based on a list of names

Tags: java, sorting, collections, set

I have a java `Set` and I can't change it to a `TreeSet` although i could copy it over.  Here is the issue:

I have names , tower, car, building , office , basement.   I have a POJO which has a string label variable containing one of these for each instance.

how can i sort these to be the EXACT order of  tower, car, building , office , basement.  There will be no duplicates allowed of course(its a set).

```
public class Places{

String label;
int moreinfo;
}
```

so imagine I have 10 Places objects with labels that could be any of  tower, car, building , office , basement: how can I sort these in a set to ensure that they are in the exact order of  "tower, car, building , office , basement" ?

Comment: Modify `Places` to implement `Comparable<Places>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Map to define an order for an arbitrary set of Strings:

```
private static Map<String, Integer> ordering;
static {
    ordering = new HashMap<>();
    ordering.add("tower", 1);
    ordering.add("car", 2");
    ...add your other strings with increasing values...
}

Collections.sort(yourCollection, new Comparator<Places>() {
    public int compare(Places p1, Places p2) {
        return ordering.get(p1.label) - ordering.get(p2.label);
    }
});
```

Be careful, however... you can't sort a Set. If it's a SortedSet (like a TreeSet) it will sort itself, if it's not it has no defined order.

Comment: PS Naturally if you are using Java 8 you can use a lambda to create the comparator

Answer (score 1):

You could turn field 'label' into enum in which enum values are ordered by your custom order.

```
public enum Label {
    TOWER, CAR, BUILDING, OFFICE, BASEMENT
}
```

Then, you can implement a comparable in order to sort the set.

```
class Places implements Comparable<Places>{

    Label label;
    int moreinfo;
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Places o) {
        return label.compareTo(o.label);
    }   
}
```

You can then use Collections.sort method for your sorting.

Comment: creative answer but i cant change my implementation. Label is a String in my code.  Plus one.